# How to automate Chrome extension upload using server keys?

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension, automation, continuous-integration, chrome-web-store

Have anyone succeeded in using server keys to authenticate Chrome Web Store API calls? Or is there another way to automate extension deployment?

---

I have created an extension in the chrome store, and I'd like to include its deployment in our CI pipeline, so that it's automatically updated in the Chrome Web Store when its code is changed by the team and all tests pass.

There is a Google API that *appeared* to do just that: [Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index). It obviously requires authentication with a Google dev account, which can take 2 forms:

- with a server key
- using OAuth 2.0

For our use-case **server key seems more appropriate**, and that's what the "credential wizard" suggested to me. Great. Except that after hours of searching **I was unable to find how to use a server key** to authenticate my REST calls.

For some reason, everyone seems to be [using the Web Store API with an OAuth token instead. [The docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) explain the process to use OAuth, and I've found [this](https://github.com/c301/grunt-webstore-upload/blob/master/tasks/webstore_upload.js) script that automates most of it, but it still requires user interaction for authorizing the OAuth. Also, I understand that this user must be logged in with the Google account used for the initial extension publication.